# react setState array of object property failed with map es6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Trying to update a state of a array of object but somehow it doesn't reflect in the state.

```
set_is_core = (selected_id) => {

  const { main } = this.state

  const next_main = main.map(o => {
    if(o.main_id === selected_id){
      console('trigger') //true
      return ({
        ...o,
        is_core: true
      })
    }
    return o
  })

  this.setState({
    main: next_main
  }, ()=> console.log(this.state.main.some(o => o.is_core))//false?)
}
```

Couldn't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: can show the structure of your state?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to map over an object. Only arrays can be mapped over using es6. You can either change your `main` variable structure to be an array or use lodash map which will allow you map over an object https://lodash.com/docs#map

Something like this for example:

```
import {map} from 'lodash'

...

set_is_core = (selected_id) => {

  const { main } = this.state

  const next_main = map(main, (o) => {
    if(o.main_id === selected_id){
      console('trigger') //true
      return ({
        ...o,
        is_core: true
      })
    }
    return o
  })

  this.setState({
    main: next_main
  }, ()=> console.log(this.state.main.some(o => o.is_core))//false?)
}
```